# equivalent of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] of PHP in Python , or get domain name in python django

Tags: python, django

I am working with Python and the Django framework. When I want to use hyperlinks , I shouldn't write the full URL manually right ? I have to use some function that returns domain names , and concatenate the path to it manually. So, how can I get the domain name ?
Like:

> http://www.domain.com/path/to/file.ext

For this, I want to write :

```
"http://"+somefunction()+"/path/to/file.ext"
```

Is there an equivalent of `$_SERVER['HTTP_URI']` in Python.

Comment: @ramesh kumar This might depend on your Apache / Nginx HTTP configuration also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your needs django offers [Sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framefork

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.get_current().domain
'example.com'
>>> 'http://%s/path/to/file.ext' % Site.objects.get_current().domain
'http://example.com/path/to/file.ext'
```

Answer (score 2):

For original host of current request, you could use [`request.get_host()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) or directly access `request['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly, but Django has a host of ways of handling URL construction for you, so you don't need to hardcode things.

Inside your Python code:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def my_redir_view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('another_view'))
```

Inside a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
```

Building absolute URLs (on the relatively rare occasions they're needed):

```
redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('openid_auth'))
```

Generally you don't want to be doing manual URL construction - the above methods are your friends.